# Build responsive button with image, text and a link using css

Tags: html, css, button

I tried several things but I am out of luck. I need to build a button containing an image and text over a button background image. Also, clicking anywhere inside the button should redirect to a page, for example, google.com. This is how the button should look like

[image]

The challenge I am having is that when the button text changes or when the screen size changes, the alignment of the image and the text gets messed up. I want to wrap the button text if it is too large. How do I wrap the button text and still align everything correctly? Also, I want the button width to be the same as I have to build multiple buttons of the same size with varied texts and images. Thank you so much. A quicker solution will be appreciated as I am anxious to see what I am doing wrong. Here is the code I have so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oz279bb8/)

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" style="color: white !important; background-color: #7FFF00;padding: 25px;width: 50px;"> 
    <span style="margin-bottom: 5%;"> 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" height:100%; style="display: inline-block;" width="30" height="30" /> 
        <span style="display: inline-block;"> 
            <b><font size ="2" color="BLACK" face="Arial">CLICK ON THE IMAGE TO VIEW MORE DETAILS ABOUT THE ITEM </font> </b> 
        </span> 
    </span> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;}
#img{
  float:left;
}
#img,#text{
 display:inline;
}

#main{
  margin-top:20px;
  width:250px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:yellowgreen;
}
#container{
  margin:15px;
  }
div.clickable {
    position:relative;
}
div.clickable #mainlink {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="clickable">
<a href="www.google.com" id="mainlink">
<div id="main">
<div id="container">
<div id="img">
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="http://oer.nios.ac.in/wiki/images/thumb/4/47/Thumpsup.png/200px-Thumpsup.png"/></a>
</div>
<div id="text">
<span>Click on the image to view more about the item</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Sorry my bad I should have mentioned clicking anywhere on the button should redirect to a web page and not just clicking on the image.

Comment: Thank you so much. When the text gets way bigger, it wraps underneath the image. Is there a way to not wrap the text underneath the image? Thanks again.